# How to use TrueForAll

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of bools and I want to check if every one is set to true. I can run a loop and check it that way but I want to try to do it with `TrueForAll` method of a list. I need a predicate for that but I couldn't find a clear example for such a simple task as this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx):

```
bool alltrue = listOfBools.All(b => b);
```

It will return `false` one the first `false`.

However, since you are actually using a  `List<bool>` you can also use `List.TrueForAll` in the similar way:

```
bool alltrue = listOfBools.TrueForAll(b => b);
```

But since that is limited to a list i would prefer `Enumerable.All`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `All` method will allocate memory and be less performant than the `TrueForAll` method. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpL-fuiEfwU

Answer (score 5):

One way is: You can use `All`..

```
var result = list.All(x => x);
```

If all are `true`, `result` will be `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably it's confusing because it's too easy if you array already contains booleans:

```
List<bool> booleans;

booleans.TrueForAll(x => x);
```

or

```
booleans.All(x => x);
```